# What does pre-formatted table in HTML mean?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an html assignment and one of the criteria is :

Defined multi-column/row table - not pre-formatted.

Now I have worked with HTML for a few years but I have never heard of pre-formatted tables.

Can someone tell me what pre-formatted tables are in html?

Comment: perhaps your teacher means she wants you to use `<table>` and not `<pre>` like in http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_PRE.html ? or she means don't use a program to generate the table for you?

Comment: Why don't you ask your tutor?

Comment: this course doesnt have a tutor... and its weekend and the assignment is due tomorrow so I wont have a chance to ask the instructor and then fix it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it might be referring to a "table" laid out inside `<pre>` - that is, doing it like it's the 80s and we're still using dumb terminals.

Just use a normal table (and when returning the assignment, make sure to ask from what century their material is from).